# How to get simple csv-data from http call into a string in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, csv, http

I have an app where I want to show  data created via a http request. At the view I want show: *The population in Greenland in 2020 are 56081 persons.*

This query http://betabank.stat.gl/sq/74c8dac5-97a0-4457-ace9-057de3e1308f returns a simpel CSV-file:

*" ""2020"""
56081*

I works fine in a browser, but how to import the content in typescript in angular. See my html and typescript below.

I have tried using embed, iframe and other solutions in html, but is not working. [How to open other web sites inside angular application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56250358/how-to-open-other-web-sites-inside-angular-application)

Please help

My html:

```
<div>
  <h2>Test simpel http import</h2>
  <p>{{outputstring}} </p>
</div>
```

My typescript:

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  inputstring: string;
  inputnumber: string;
  outputstring: string;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.inputstring = "The population in Greenland in 2020 are {{}} persons.";
    this.inputnumber = "56081";

   // I need to get inputnumber from this http-call (transformed)
   // http://betabank.stat.gl/sq/74c8dac5-97a0-4457-ace9-057de3e1308f

    this.outputstring = this.inputstring.replace("{{}}", this.inputnumber);

  } 
}
```

Comment: usually rest apis returning data not file, I am not sure if you just want to get your hand dirty with http client or you really want to read the response that is comming as file?

Comment: If you only want to display the information obtained from the URL, it is better to obtain JSON data if possible. It is easier to work with compared to CSV.

Comment: That URL does not return CSV. You could get the value as a string and use a .split to break it into an array on the carriage return.

Comment: Thanks for comments. To Diodeus: I want to get the value as a string and transform it with split etc. But my problem is which methods / commands (http etc) do I use in my typescript to get this string?