# Unsafe value used in a resource URL context (iframe)

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, angular, typescript

Trying to pass value as iframe url from local db and and im getting error message:
 Unsafe value used in a resource URL context.
i'm trying to display an array of printers ip so i will be able to check their status via the website there is anyway to do this without iframe ?
i will be more then glad to hear some advises.

I'm new to angular and every help is more then welcome
thanks in advance.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-value',
  templateUrl: './value.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./value.component.css']
})


export class ValueComponent implements OnInit {
  values: any;



  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

  

ngOnInit() {
  this.getValues();


}

getValues() {
  this.http.get('http://localhost:5000/api/values/').subscribe(response => {
    this.values = response;
  }, error => {
    console.log(error);
  })
}

}
```

```html
<H2>Print Manager</H2>


<div id="outerdiv">
  <iframe src="http://192.168.1.6/general/status.html" id="inneriframe" scrolling="no"  ></iframe>
</div>



<div *ngFor="let value of values">
<p>{{value.id}},{{value.hostName}},{{value.location}},{{value.manufacturer}},{{value.ip}}</p>

<span>Hostname: {{value.hostName}}</span>
<br>
<span>Location: {{value.location}}</span>
<br>
<span>Manufacturer: {{value.manufacturer}}</span>
<br>
<span>IP: {{value.ip}}</span>

</div>
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You may use Angular `DomSanitizer` from `@angular/platform-browser`

Refer [Angular Guide](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer) for more info

```
import {DomSanitizationService} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'temp.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
yourUrl : '';
  constructor(private sanitizer : DomSanitizationService) {  
  }

  getSanitizedURL() {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(yourUrl);
  }
}
```

HTML :

```
   <div id="outerdiv">
      <iframe src="getSanitizedURL()" id="inneriframe" scrolling="no"></iframe>
    </div>
```

Comment: Error is displayed yet after apply this solution

Answer (score 10):

Using a **Pipe** is better.

**Create a **[Pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes)**:** In the **app.component.ts** *(The main component that loads first)*

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform} from "@angular/core";
import { DomSanitizer } from "@angular/platform-browser";

@Pipe({ name: 'safe' })
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }
  transform(url) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
  }
}
```

**Declare the Pipe:**
After creating the pipe

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ ... ],
  declarations: [ ..., SafePipe ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
```

**Usage:** You can use this with the pipe operator and the pipe name.

**Example:**

```
 <iframe [src]="your_url_here | safe" id="inneriframe" scrolling="no"  ></iframe>
```

Using this method, you will get a **sanitized URL** without rewriting the code every time you need it in other components.

Answer (score -1):

[src]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('http://'+value.ip+'/general/status.html')"
solved it for me